# What is a simple way to disable a given postgresql database cluster?

Tags: postgresql

I can use `pg_ctlcluster ver cluster stop` to stop the service of a given cluster but if the machine reboots it starts right back up again. I could do something like change the data directory in it's postgresql.conf file but that smells to me.

Comment: try `sudo find /etc/postgresql -name start.conf`?..

Comment: try `sudo update-rc.d postgresql disable` if you are on ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL installations that have `pg_ctlcluster` (Debian-based) look for a `start.conf` file in `/etc/postgresql/<version>/<clustername>` with these contents:

```
# Automatic startup configuration
# auto: automatically start/stop the cluster in the init script
# manual: do not start/stop in init scripts, but allow manual startup with
#         pg_ctlcluster
# disabled: do not allow manual startup with pg_ctlcluster (this can be easily
#           circumvented and is only meant to be a small protection for
#           accidents).

auto
```

Put **manual** instead to avoid auto-starting at boot, per-cluster.